# sql group by end of the week on Sundays

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-date-functions

I have 3 columns in my table:

```
bill_date (daily data), country, revenues
```

How to group by country and get sum of revenues if I want to group my bill_date by the end of every week that fall on Sundays ?

To be clearer for the current month ,November 2023 I would like to get following:

- from day 1th November to sunday 5th November : week 1 ( 1 day of month, no matter which day it is , until 1th sunday of the month )
- from 6 November to sunday 12th November : week 2 (week from monday to sunday)
- from 13th November to sunday 19th November : week 3 (week from monday to sunday)
- from 20th November to sunday 26th : week 4 (week from monday to sunday)
- from 27th to thursday 30th : week 5
  ( for the last week of every month, I would like to select all the days always starting from monday until the last day of the month, no matter which day will be the end of the month)

I have tried with week `datepart` function using SQL Server Management Studio 2018 version but with no success... I cannot see dateweek function in SQL Server Management Studio 2018 ...

Comment: SSMS is a DBA tool, not a database server. No matter what database version you use, the *easy* solution is to use a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) with eg 10-20 years of dates and extra columns for year, month, quarter, semester, week or any other reporting period you want.

Comment: *"SQL Server Management Studio 2018 "* there is no such thing. Do you mean SSMS *18*? That was released in *2019* and supports SQL Server 2008-2019, Azure Synapse, Azure SQL Database, etc, so doesn't help us understand the product you are using.

Comment: In the latest version of SQL the `DATE_BUCKET` function would likely be what you want.

Comment: MS SQL version 18.6 . I cannot find DATE_BUCKET built-in function unfortunately

Comment: *"MS SQL version 18.6 .* that doesn't exist either; we only got SQL Server 16 (SQL Server 2022) last year. And that's only on version 16.0.4095.4. It's quite rare for a version of SQL Server to have a minor revision (only SQL server 2008 did in recent memory), but certainly not 6 of them. If you really are using 18.6, you've obtained a version from maybe 10 years in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it can help, in Python, (and in general the algorithm) would be:

```
df['week'] = (
np.ceil(
(
df['DATE'].dt.day
- 7 +
df['DATE'].dt.to_period('M').dt.start_time.dt.dayofweek
)
/7)
).astype(int) + 1
```

you're using the first day of each month to establish when the first week of the month ends.
example: first day is Monday. you'll have week calculated as
ceil((1 - 7 + 0)/7) + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
Tuesday: ceil((2 - 7 + 0)/7) + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
...
the first next Monday: ceil((8 - 7 + 0)/7) + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2
and so on

if the first day of the week was Sunday, you'd get ceil((1-7+6)/7) + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
but on the second day ceil((2-7+6)/7) + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2

the offset must equal the .dt.dayofweek of the first day of the month (because Monday = 0)

Comment: Something is not quire right with the above. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MW4RnnZK). First the absence of an explicit `SET DATEFIRST 1` may cause *Sunday-through-Saturday* calculations instead of *Monday-through-Sunday* in some environments. It also appears be be combining the first two weeks. For example, I believe October 2023 should have 6 week periods of lengths {1,7,7,7,7,2}, but the above groups the first two together together yielding weeks of lengths {8,7,7,7,2}. (Other months have similar results.)

Comment: you're right, I will delete the SQL part to not confuse people!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to group your data both by **month and week** to get the right output.

To group by week specify the first day of week as Monday with `SET DATEFIRST 1` and group the data with `DATEPART(wk, bill_date)`.

To group by month use `CONVERT(nvarchar(7), bill_date, 121)` to get the first 7 characters of a the date ISO-formatted.

```
 -- Set first day of week to Monday
SET DATEFIRST 1;

-- Generate some data and put it into a table
DECLARE @data TABLE (bill_date date, country nvarchar(max), revenues int)

-- Generate 500 rows
;WITH r AS (SELECT top 500 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id) as n FROM sys.all_objects)

-- Insert into a table
INSERT INTO @data
SELECT
  DATEADD(DAY, r.n, '2022-12-31'), -- Start at the beginning of 2023 and take 500 days
  country.name,
  r.n * country.factor -- use a country factor to get different values for each country
FROM r
-- Cross apply with a few countries
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1, 'SE'), (2, 'NO'), (3, 'FI')) AS country(factor, name)

-- Select data grouped by week and month
SELECT
  country,
  MAX(bill_date) AS last_day_week,
  SUM(revenues) revenue_sum
FROM @data
GROUP BY
  DATEPART(wk, bill_date), -- Group by week
  CONVERT(nvarchar(7), bill_date, 126), -- .. and by month
  country
ORDER BY MAX(bill_date), country
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the *period-ending* date by separately calculating the *last-day-of-the-week* and *last-day-of-the-month* and taking the lesser of the two. This can be wrapped up in a `CROSS APPLY` and the result used in the `GROUP BY`, `SELECT`, and `ORDER BY` clauses.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1  -- Set Monday as first day of week

SELECT country, period_ending, SUM(revenues) AS revenues
FROM @Data
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN DATEADD(day, 7 - DATEPART(weekday, bill_date), CONVERT(DATE, bill_date))
             < EOMONTH(bill_date)
        THEN DATEADD(day, 7 - DATEPART(weekday, bill_date), CONVERT(DATE, bill_date))
        ELSE EOMONTH(bill_date)
        END AS period_ending
) PE
GROUP BY country, period_ending
ORDER BY country, period_ending
```

If using SQL Server 2022 or later, the `DATETRUNC()` and `LEAST()` functions simplify the calculations.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1  -- Set Monday as first day of week

SELECT country, period_ending, SUM(revenues) AS revenues
FROM @Data
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT LEAST(
            DATEADD(day, 6, DATETRUNC(week, bill_date)),
            EOMONTH(bill_date)
        ) AS period_ending
) PE
GROUP BY country, period_ending
ORDER BY country, period_ending
```

The `DATEBUCKET()` function can also be used if you wish to avoid `SET DATEFIRST`.

Comment: your first results only gives me values until sunday 5th november , just week 1 and not the others weeks 2, 3 , 4, 5

Comment: @Andreabic - Can you double check your results? I ran my queries against some generated test data and got what I believe are the expected results.  See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BnhFIISh). The `@FromDate` and `@ThruDate` values can be adjusted to test different date ranges. It also includes Kristofer's query at the end, which yields similar results, except for some of the end dates.  If you are still showing issues, please post your test data, results, and a statement of where the actual results differ from expected.

Comment: [This modified db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pZ0vJDrS) has a modified test data generator will also run in SQL Server 2019 or earlier. Select the run version from the dropdown at the top. It also contains a corrected year-month-week calculation that supports up to 6 weeks per month in the form "2023-10-w6".